# arrayformula to populate formula in google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this line in my script:
`sheet.getRange(1,1).setFormula("=sum(D1*E1*F1)")`
and I would like to populate this in all the rows below `(1,1)`, so I go with:
`sheet.getRange(1,1).setFormula("=ARRAYFORMULA(if(D1:D,D1:D*(E1:E*F1:F),""))")`
but this doesn't work in a script. It works when I just type it in a cell manually, but it just gives me error when I run it from a script.
No idea, what's wrong, thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, sorry for a mistake, a was typing the formula from my head and mixed one with another. I edited my question so it should be as it should now. So Range(1,1) is A1 to make it simple. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: I still get this error: `"Missing ) after argument list. (line 19, file "Code")"` and the line 19 is: `sheet.getRange(1,1).setFormula("=ARRAYFORMULA(if(D1:D500,D1:D500*(E1:E500*F1:F500),""))") `

Comment: Locale is United States

Answer (score 0):

you may have an issue with the quotation marks. Can you try if this works (note the single quotes at the beginning and end)...

```
sheet.getRange(1,1).setFormula('=ARRAYFORMULA(if(D1:D,D1:D*(E1:E*F1:F),""))');
```